# Blank page insertion not always working

Tags: miktex, texmaker, blank-page

In my document I need:
- Cover page
- Blank page
- Thanks page
- Blank page
- Then content starts

I successfully instead the first blank page, but the second blank page after Thanks page doesn't want to show up. How can I insert that second blank page?

Edit: I noticed that my blank page(s) actually appear, but they go after table of content while they should appear before.

Here is my current code, with anonymised text placeholder :

Main.tex

```
%Preamble
\documentclass[a4paper,french,oneside,openright]{book}

\usepackage{afterpage}
\newcommand{\blankpage}{
    \null
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \addtocounter{page}{-1}
    \newpage
    }

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{tocloft,calc}
\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{Chapter }
\AtBeginDocument{\addtolength\cftchapnumwidth{\widthof{\bfseries Chapter }}}


\title{Title}
\author{Name}
\date{2020}
\pagestyle{myheadings}
\begin{document}
    \input{Pages/TitlePage.tex}
    \input{Pages/Thanks.tex}


    \tableofcontents


    \chapter{Introduction}
        \section{Introduction}
        \lipsum
    \chapter{Chapter title}
        \section{SectionTitle}
        \lipsum
    \chapter{Chapter title}
        \section{SectionTitle}
        \lipsum
    \chapter{Chapter title}
        \section{SectionTitle}
        \lipsum
    \chapter{Chapter title}
        \section{SectionTitle}
        \lipsum
    \chapter{Chapter title}
        \section{SectionTitle}
        \lipsum
    \chapter{Chapter title}
        %\section{SectionTitle}  %Testing what happens in table of contents when there is a chapter without section.
        \lipsum
    \chapter{Chapter title}
        \section{SectionTitle}
        \lipsum
\end{document}
```

TitlePage.tex

```
\begin{titlepage}
    \newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}

    \HRule \\[0.9cm]
    \begin{center}
        \textsc{\Huge Title}\\[1cm]
        \textsc{\LARGE Subtitle}\\[1.5cm]
    \end{center}
    \HRule \\[1.5cm]

    \begin{center} \Large
        \begin{tabular}{ l r }  
            \emph{Text} & Text\\ 
            \emph{Text} & Text
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}

    \vfill

    \begin{center} \large
        \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l r @{}}
            \ Text & Text\\
            \ Text & Text\\
            \ Text & Text\\
            \ Text & Text\\
            \ Text & Text
        \end{tabular*}
    \end{center}
    \afterpage{\blankpage}
\end{titlepage}
```

Thanks.tex

```
\part*{Remerciements}
\afterpage{\blankpage}
```

Thanks.tex (alternate try)

```
\part*{Remerciements}
\afterpage{\blankpage}

\afterpage{\blankpage}
```

Comment: You should make this into a single document, much easier for others to handle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using

```
\blankpage
```

instead of

```
\afterpage{\blankpage}
```

in Thanks.text file.